# can checking the hits from a raycast cause the game to crash?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so i am trying to detect if i click on a object with tag "solarsystem" and if so, then load that solarsystem onto the other scene. this code worked perfectly fine before, but now it crashes in such a way that i have to end unity from the task manager with the end task button to even close it. it just stops responding completely.

here is the code where i believe to have found the error after messing around with many Debug.log s to find where the code stopped and therefore find out where unity stops responding:

```
    RaycastHit[] hit = Physics.RaycastAll(cursorPosition, Vector3.forward,15f);
        Debug.Log("test2");//this is printed to the console - code crashes below this line
        for(int i = 0; i < hit.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("hit"); // this is never printed to console - code crashes above this line
            if(currentScene == "Universe")
            {
                if(hit[i].collider.gameObject.tag == "SolarSystem")
                {
                    ChangeScene("SolarSystem");
                    SolarSystem clickedSolarSystem = hit[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SystemObjectLink>().LinkedClass;
                    SolarSystem LoadedSolarSystem = SolarSystemCamera.GetComponent<SolarSystem>() as SolarSystem;
                    LoadedSolarSystem = clickedSolarSystem;
                    Debug.Log("generating system clicked on");
                    if (LoadedSolarSystem.preGenerated == false)
                    {
                        LoadedSolarSystem.Generate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LoadedSolarSystem.Regenerate();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(currentScene == "SolarSystem")
            {
                if (hit[i].collider != null)
                {
                    if (hit[i].collider.gameObject.tag == "Planet")
                    {
                        Target = hit[i].collider.gameObject;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (hit[i].collider.gameObject.tag == "Moon")
                    {
                        Target = hit[i].collider.gameObject;
                        break;
                    }
                    Target = hit[i].collider.gameObject;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is `cursorPosition` of type `Ray`? [Physics.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html)

Comment: `Debug.Log(hit.Length);`?

Comment: I take that back. I didn't see the overload below with RaycastAll(Vector3, Vector3, ...)

Comment: Where you have `Debug.Log("test2")`, put `hit.Length` as the string instead. Does it still crash?

Comment: okay, so i changed "test2" to hit.Length and it still worked as before. when i clicked on nothing it printed "0" to the console, but the second it hits something it stops responding completely and i have to end the task in task manager. keep the suggestions coming and i'll keep trying them (also cursorPosition is a Vector3 -  the screen to world point of the cursor on the screen)

Comment: Leave just the debug.log in your for loop and see if it prints when you hit something. If it doesn't crash I bet the problem is with one of your functions (ChangeScene, LoadedSolarSystem). From my experience Unity crashes like this mainly in case of infinite loops. Comment out line by line to check which line/function is causing the problem.

Comment: i already have a debug log in my loop. but it "crashes" before it prints any of that. so it doesnt make sense to me ( hence why i'm on here asking) because it has a infinite loop between debug.log("test2") and debug.log("hit") and i dont know why

Comment: Please do the test as I wrote and let me know if you get the "hit" log. You may not see the log because the editor freeze before the log is printed to the console.

Comment: okay i did the test. when i click on something it crashes before it does the debug log.  so you're telling me that the loop is kind of "pre processed" for infinite loops before it runs. and if it finds any it gets stuck in the infinite loop before it can actually run the code

Comment: What I am trying to say is lines after debug.log may be still called and you cannot see the log in your console because one of these lines crashed the unity. If this is the case then it is not the code in between your logs that is causing the problem but the code after the second debug.log. Logs may be printed to the console with some delay.

Comment: Remove everything from your for loop after the Debug.Log("hit"); and you should not get the error.

Comment: i'll make those changes and have another glance over any loops that may be effecting this. i think i have an idea what may be causing this so i'll sleep and get some rest and get back to you guys tomorrow and let you know of my findings

Comment: okay so i fixed it. it turns out that when i clicked on an object. the unity engine decided to  give all the code a dry-run (meaning that it looks through the code - possibly checking for errors before it goes over it again and actually runs the code) so during this dry-run the unity engine gets stuck in an infinite loop i left behind. i had hardcoded a way to get out of the infinite loop but because it was only running a dry-run and not actually running the code, the engine didn't recognise the hardcoded escape and got stuck infinitely checking the loop for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had an `for(;;)` statement with a hardcoded

```
    if(<state>){
        break:
    }
```

statement to break the infinite loop. but as i click on an object in the game. it checks the code for any errors before running it. when it does this it gets caught in the infinite loop and so to fix it i did this

```
    for(;errorIndex<99; errorIndex++){

    }
```

**my mistake and what i learned:**

never use a `while(true)` loop or a for loop without a way of getting out of itself (`for(;;)`)

if the unity engine/editor ever stops responding it is because it is cought in an infinite loop- look over your code and ensure there is no possible way any of your loops can go on forever